# Problem applying Cauchy's estimate in proof

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ is an analytic map from the unit disk to itself.

Taylor series of $f$ centered at 0: $f=\sum_n a_n z^n$ ).

Prove that: $|a_n|\leq 1 \; \forall n$

I've started using Cauchy's estimate:
$|a_n|=\frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}\leq \frac{M_r}{r^n}$ with $M_r=\max\{|f(z)|: |z|=r\}$

We see that: $M_r\leq 1 $ and $r=1$. But why is this ($M_r\leq 1 $ and $r=1$) the case ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have $M_r \leqslant 1$ because by assumption $f$ maps the unit disk to itself, so $\lvert f(z)\rvert < 1$ for all $z$ with $\lvert z\rvert < 1$.

The assumptions don't allow you to set $r = 1$, since $f$ need not be defined, let alone continuous, on the boundary of the disk, the circle $\lvert z\rvert = 1$. But you have

$$\lvert a_n \rvert \leqslant \frac{M_r}{r^n} \leqslant \frac{1}{r^n}$$

**for all** $r < 1$, so you can take the limit $r \to 1$ to conclude $\lvert a_n\rvert \leqslant 1$.